# modify and replace value in char array in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, while-loop

As the program showed, I don't know what is wrong for printing out the new result.
e.g. when I finished calling modify_str() function with position=0, value=v,
it won't appear "vello" as result but throw a short gibberish. 
Can anyone identify the error!? Thanks:)

```
#include<stdio.h>
void print_(char *abc);
void modify_str(char *a);

void main(){
    char c[20]="Hello";
    print_(c);

    modify_str(c);

}


void print_(char *str){
    int i=0;
    while(*(str+i) != '\0'){
        printf("%c", str[i]);
        i++;
    }
    printf("\n");
}

void modify_str(char *c){
    char q[]="Position of char to modify (0-n): ";
    print_(q);
    int pos;
    scanf("%d", &pos);

    printf("value to replace: ");
    char w;
    scanf("%s", &w);

    int index=0;
    while(*(c+index) !='\0'){
        if(index==pos){
            c[index]=w;
            printf("New Result: %c\n", c);
        }
        index++;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's `int main`, not `void main` in C. C is not Java. And not testing the return value from scanf() is **always a bug**.

Comment: You love`void`. you love `while()`

Comment: Change it like [this](http://ideone.com/eNcGbB)

Comment: @BLUEPIXY why do you keep posting your very good answers off-site? Would you be first to object to off-site questions?

Comment: @WeatherVane Because nobody needs it.

Comment: You under value yourself.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY hi sorry one more question: why do we need a white space before the %c in scarf?

Comment: If it is absent, a newline (whitespaces) is received as input.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of this call with the incorrect format specifier

```
scanf("%s", &w);
```

use

```
scanf(" %c", &w);
       ^^^
```

The while loop should look like

```
while( *(c+index) !='\0' && index != pos ) ++index;

if ( index == pos && *( c + index ) != '\0' )
{
        c[index]=w;
        printf("New Result: %s\n", c);
                            ^^  
}
```

Also it is a bad idea to name a string with the identifier `c` that is usually used for naming objects of type `char`. It is better to use identifier `s`.

Take into account that according to the C Standard the function main without parameters shall be declared like

```
int main( void )
```

By the way the function `print_` can be implemented like

```
void print_( const char *str )
{
    puts( str );
}
```

And do not use trailing underscores in identifiers.  It is just a bad programming style.

Comment: But now I cannot implement the inside print_new_result statement.

Comment: maybe the condition blocked the printing.

Comment: @Y.Andy This statement should be outside the loop. There is no reason for placing it inside the while loop. You can move the call of printf outside the if statement.

Comment: Cheers! You are very helpful 